# FreeMarker check if not null for SimpleNumber - returning even if null

Tags: java, freemarker, templating

I've been finding a ton of resources on how to check if not null on here, but for some reason my "include" will run regardless of whether or not there's a value in the field. My data type according to our ESP is "freemarker.template.SimpleNumber".

Here's the code (with the actual fields renamed for the example)

```
<#if subscriber.childAcct??>
<#data Content_table as content>
<#filter Reference_Name = "Child Account Content">
<#fields Content>
<#include "relative link/${content.Content}">
</#data>
<#else>
</#if>
```

I plan on chaining two more else-if conditions and a default include for the else on here once I get this one to function properly. This check is just to see if there's a number in the child account field, and if so, include the content within that field, else continue to the next check, and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you are saying that `subscriber.childAcct` is `null`, yet the inside of that `#if` runs. Very strange. What if you try to do `${subscriber.childAcct}` in such case? Does it print anything, or just dies (as it should)?